# Laravel 5 - TokenMismatchException

Tags: php, laravel

I migrate my web application to other server and after that I have this error:

> TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 46:

it is strange because in other forms everythink work perfect like before, only in one page I have this error.
Of course I have this line in my form:

```
<input name="_token" type="hidden" value="{{{ csrf_token() }}}" />
```

I try to clean cache, add permission to vendor,storage. Clean this directory and all the time error back..

In my broswer I clean cookie and cache and I have still this error.

```
<form action="{{url('video/upload')}}" id="qq-form">
    <input name="_token" type="hidden" value="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
{{ csrf_token() }}
```

Instead of:

```
{{{ csrf_token() }}}
```

Or just use `csrf_field()` to build form element:

```
{{ csrf_field() }}
```

You've said you're using Dropzone. In this case, you also need to setup [`X-CSRF-TOKEN`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token). In Blade template:

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

In JS:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure both options will work for you if you use it right. Please show the exact code you're trying to use now and what error do you get?

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin You can simply disable CSRF token if your issue has not resolved.

Comment: Added in topic, I use dropzone js script

Comment: @Jensej in this case, you also need to setup `X-CSRF-TOKEN`. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Still this error. But sth is strange, because Only in my notebook I have this error, when I upload from smartphone, everythink work good

Comment: I use nginx it could be a reason?

Answer (score 0):

If you use AJAX or something like that to submit the form. Add the:

```
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });
```

before your ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

You need to place that {{ csrf_field() }} outside of other elements. So think of it as it's own element. Not something you place as an attribute. I always use mine like.

```
<form>
{{ csrf_field() }}
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `csrf_field()` like below in your blade file after opening your form:

```
{{ csrf_field() }}
```

Or you can add below code in your head section:

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

If you use AJAX, keep below code to your ajax call:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  headers: {
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
  }
});
```

If still **TokenMismatchException error** is coming then **disable CSRF token** from specific routes by modifying app/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php

```
class VerifyCsrfToken extends BaseVerifier
{

 // The URIs that should be excluded from CSRF verification.

    protected $except = [
    "/*"
    ];
}
```

*Though the above procedure can resolve your issue but it is not recommended to disable CSRF token so use it only if you are in hurry to resolve issue and can later modify your code.*